# Are almost all subsets with cardinality at least the connectivity also separating sets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G:=(V,E)$ be a graph. If $S \subseteq V(G)$ and $G-S$ is not connected, then $S$ is a *separating set*. The *vertex connectivity*, denoted by $\kappa(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the cardinality of a minimum separating set of $G$.

The problem mentioned in the question originates from my computation of the toughness of a graph.

**Toughness** of a graph $G$ is defined as
$$
t(G)=\min _S \frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}
$$
where $c$ is the number of connected components and the minimum is **taken over all separating sets** $S$ of $G$ (Graph toughness was first introduced by Václav Chvátal (1973)).

According to the definition of toughness, there is also an equivalent definition.

$$
t(G)=\min _S \frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}
$$
where $c$ is the number of connected components and the minimum is taken over **all nonempty property subset $S$  of the vertex set $V$ with cardinality  $ \ge \kappa(G)$.**

For a graph with connectivity $k$, the cardinality of the separating set is always greater than or equal to $k$. So, among the proper subsets with a cardinality at least $k$, what is the proportion occupied by the separating set? Is it close to 1? If so, trying to find all separating sets first would hardly improve computational efficiency for the toughness.

More formally, let  $G$  be a random graph with $n$ vertices of vertex connectivity  $k$. Then we seek $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\text { number of separating sets }}{\text { number of proper subsets with cardinality } \geq k}.$$

Comment: This depends on how you sample $G$. If you take a uniform distribution over all graphs of $n$ vertices and some constant connectivity $k$, you probably get a single vertex of degree $k$ in an otherwise random graph. Most proper subsets of cardinality $\geq k$ will have size around $n/2$, so the probability such a set is a separator is about $2^{-k} - 2^{-k-1}$.